# Angularjs ng-clip & zeroclipboard is not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on clip-copy but it is not working, I've added sample code in plunker.

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/LxSRxLNYI3bP5VIkB450`
```

Comment: check that, Example package should contain working code for you  https://github.com/asafdav/ng-clip

Comment: I saw this code, it is not working :(